# what does MediaPlayer mediaPlayer do...? in java android

Tags: java, android

```
import android.media.MediaPlayer;

public class Mainactivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    public void play(View view){
        mediaPlayer.start();
```

Does '`MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;`' same as `MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = New MediaPlayer();`?
If not, what does '`MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;`' do?

Comment: It's a constant. You'll have to initialize it later.

MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = New MediaPlayer (); it's the same thing, only that you declare and initialize the variable at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not the same.

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
```

would be the same as `MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();`

The `MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;` is a declaration of this variable. It lets you instantiate it (create an object) at a different time than the declaration of this variable - for example in a constructor or a method.